# Creating the analogue of BigInteger.ZERO for own data type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, custom-data-type

So, as is well-known, Kotlin is able to access Java libraries, and among them is the BigInteger class. And this class has a very handy feature: There is a keyword, called "BigInteger.ZERO", which returns a BigInteger object whose value equals zero.

Now I am writing a fraction data type, and I'd very much like to do the same thing for it. But the problem with just putting a val inside the class is that this first needs an object to begin with; it's not a "static" constant, so to say.

I'd be very grateful indeed for any forthcoming replies.

Comment: Are you looking for a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)? You can declare such a `val` inside a `companion object` of your class.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, this is what I was looking for. I just didn't know the right search term...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the constant as a `val` inside the companion object of your class:

```
class Fraction {
    ...
    companion object {
        val ZERO = Fraction()
    }
}
```

Then you can call your constant by `Fraction.ZERO`.

Note that this only makes sense if your fraction class is immutable.

Comment: Actually, the official page uses a slightly different syntax: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects But it's certainly what I meant. Is this discrepancy intentional? If not, clearing it up will result in me accepting & upvoting your answer.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous What different syntax? Do you mean the fact that it has a name? That is optional, as explained further down that page.

Comment: OK, so the specs say the code will work, but I'll probably give the companion object a name. For some reason, this option feels more consistent with the specs to me and a bit less artificial. The answer is not wrong, but it's not the way I'm going to do it. What am I to do? Edit?

Comment: OK, I'll just accept the answer anyway, my comment should suffice for the orientation of any future reader.